# Problems when displaying Chinese symbols shorter Win32 STATIC control

Tags: winapi, win32gui

I'm trying to put several Chinese symbols in a static control which is not enough bigger to keep them all. The result is:

[image: Chinese on 2 lines]

As you can see some of the symbols are moved on the second line. This issue is not observed with Latin letters.

EDIT: Adding SS_SIMPLE style to the Chinese static, solves the problem, but I'm wondering why there is such a difference between Chinese and Latin text rendering?

Thanks,
Kalin

Comment: Chinese fonts need more space. Make your control bigger.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: The static control isn't large enough for the Latin text either. You can see a partially visible character at the right edge. The question (as I understand it) is, why does the Latin text not wrap around to the next line, while the Chinese text does.

Comment: Chinese and English have different line breaking rules.

English uses spaces to separate words, and since there are no spaces, the entire string `AAAAAAAAAAA..AAAA` is treated as one giant word which cannot be broken.

Chinese does not use spaces to separate words. Line breaks are allowed after any character. Therefore, Chinese text has a line break opportunity as soon as the right hand edge of the static control is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Add `SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP` style to remove second line. Another solution is to change CY (height) of static control. It must be 8 logical points.